# Running a local git server, and connecting to it with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

Hello people of the internet

For a long time, I've been programming by myself, so I haven't had a need for project management, and programs to do version control.
If I wanted to create a new version, I just created a copy on my laptop, did some new code, and I was done.
Fortunately, business is good, and I've hired new programmers, so now my challenge is how do I manage all this.

I have spent the weekend, trying to learn Git, and how to get it working on Visual Studio, and I can't figure this out.

My first question is, can I host my code on my local machine?
I downloaded Git for windows, which I assume is a Git server (for lack of better words).
I setup my Git folder (Git Bash here), placed my code in there, which I assume acts like my "code server."

I then want to be able to get a copy of that code in Visual Studio, in my directory where I code locally.
Essentially, this would be my local version of the code.
After hours of trying, I managed to get a copy of the code.

Then, I wanted to modify the code in my local copy, and upload it to my "Git server."
That didn't work, and I have forgotten the error message now, as I've tried so many things, and deleted and added things.

O also, we are coding in PHP, JS, css, etc.

If I can tackle this another way, basically, I have a small team of coders, and I want to have a way to let the team, grab and check in code, in the office.
How can we do that?

Visual Studio is also not great.
Personally, I code in NotePad ++.
The only reason that I've switched over to Visual Studio is because I want:
1) an editor that tracks which pages have been changed
2) has the facility to upload changed scripts to a code server

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

A lot to unpack there. First I want to just add some clarity to the role git plays with your applications. Git is known as source control and will allow multiple people to work in the same application(s). You should definitely check out some documentation and video tutorials on git.

To answer your first question. Your code is not on a server, local or otherwise. You’re going to need to set up your local machine to be a server. I would recommend XAMPP to do this. The A in XAMPP stands for Apache and that’s what’s going to make your local server for you. This application also plays nice with the LAMP stack. And you will use this in tandem with Git. (GitHub, Platform, AWS, GitLab)

To your second question. Once you’ve made a modification to the code you’ll want to test it in both production and locally. To do that you’ll just go to the url you selected for your Apache server and push you code via git to your staging branch. (Default branch is master)

But what you’ve described is pretty popular and XAMPP is used wildly with php apps and Wordpress (also a php app)

I hope this helped.